# what's equivalent to PrintDocument of C# in C/C++?

Tags: c++, printing

I'm looking for an code example/library or something that to be equivalent to PrintDocument in C and/or C++ languages. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a language feature. You'll have to use a framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: [Documents and Printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In managed C+/CLI, its also `PrintDocument`    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx

Comment: C++/CLI is not C++ though, so I don't think this is the answer he is looking for